# Table name not Creating in Excel graph api

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a table in excel using graph api but I'm not able to set the table name.

```
POST call: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!4IXXX-XXX/list/items/39/driveitem/workbook/worksheets('MeTest')/tables/add
```

Header: Content-type: application/json

BODY:

```
{
"address": "OFFSET('MeTest'!A1,0,0,SUBTOTAL(103,'MeTest'!$A:$A),17)",
"hasHeaders": true, 
"name":"MYTABLE"
}
```

I have tried, ...tables("MYTABLE"), tables('MYTABLE'), tables/MYTABLE/add but nothing seems to work. The post is a success but the system names the table Table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a limitation of the workbook API. When creating a new table, the name is set automatically.

You need to make another call to update the table and change the name

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/list/items/{item_id}/driveitem/workbook/worksheets('{sheet_name}')/tables/{table_id}
{
    "name":"MYTABLE"
}
```

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that. So there is no other way to set the name from the first call? You absolutely need that id and then you can set it?

Comment: What I know, the Graph API internally call Excel JS API, so the limitations is in Excel API itself. [Add table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.tablecollection?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-tablecollection-add-member(1)) function accept only address and hasHeaders. Graph API patch calls [set properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.table?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-table-set-member(2)) function

Comment: I haven't not tested the call you provided but it looks correct and I will test it now and then mark your answer. I appreciate your help